# Canvas tag - rectangle not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am learning canvas tag. I tried out a simple think of drawing a rectangle inside the canvas. While I can see the canvas I can't see the rectangle displayed. I have tried pushing my main canvas at the back with z-index. Still nothing.

```js
let draw = getElementById('myCanvas');
let ctx = draw.getContext('2d') // creating the rectangle 
ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
ctx.fillRect(75, 75, 150, 150);
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid red;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `document` for  `getElementById()`:

`let draw = document.getElementById('myCanvas');`

More information about `getElementById()`: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

The `z-index: -1` doesn't have any affect. Further, opening the console (Click `F12`) in "Developers Tools" would help you debug this error next time.

```js
let draw = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
let ctx = draw.getContext('2d') // creating the rectangle 
ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
ctx.fillRect(75, 75, 150, 150);
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid red;
  /*z-index: -1*/
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" />
```